# Found cycle for field Spring Mongo Data 1.8.2

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, testing

I'm writing a UnitTest for my app and I have de wierd bug. My app is working well but when I'm lauching my test I have the following message :

> [mongod output] 2016-01-22 12:30:37,078 INFO  DEMO [NO_USER] {main}
>   o.s.d.m.c.i.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver[doWithPersistentProperty:267]
>   - Found cycle for field 'defaultAddress' in type 'Contact' for path 'customers.contact'
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$CyclicPropertyReferenceException:
>   Found cycle for field 'defaultAddress' in type 'Contact' for path
>   'customers.contact'

It seems like @JsonIgnore annotation is ignored. I tried to put it on the property and on the getter but no changes. This message never stops looping.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

what about the annotation @Transient of org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient

Comment: Worked for me. `transient` keyword and annotation `@javax.persistence.Transient` doesn't help, but `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` works well